# FFMpeg - How to delete parts of a video that (partially) match an image

Tags: ffmpeg

I have videos that include ad breaks whereupon the frames include a big logo in the middle (and text saying ad break). I have extracted one of those frames as an image.
I want to run an ffmpeg command to delete those ad breaks (to reduce the size of the video), but still haven't found how.

After researching those parts, I think I have a command which identifies those frames that match the extracted image (based on https://superuser.com/a/1615601/1784971)

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -i image.png -filter_complex "blend=all_mode=difference,blackframe=amount=0:threshold=1,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=10:function=greater,metadata=print:file=ads.txt" -an -v 0 -f null -
```

Sample output

```
frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0
timecode=20:00:05:10
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:1    pts:1502    pts_time:0.0166889
timecode=20:00:05:11
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:2    pts:3003    pts_time:0.0333667
timecode=20:00:05:11
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:3    pts:4505    pts_time:0.0500556
timecode=20:00:05:12
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:4    pts:6006    pts_time:0.0667333
timecode=20:00:05:12
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:5    pts:7508    pts_time:0.0834222
timecode=20:00:05:13
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=13
frame:6    pts:9009    pts_time:0.1001
timecode=20:00:05:13
```

Now I don't know how to tell ffmpeg to delete/ignore those frames. Would the -select option work? If so, how to combine -select with the filter above? Those videos also have audio so I'm looking for a solution that keeps that in sync.

Thanks,